# How to change SE’s readability-destroying font?

Tags: support, feature-request

SE made a change to their fonts which seriously impairs my ability to read the site today. Is there a setting or option to change this?

Comment: This is purely a curiosity question: what makes your system fonts less readable? I find the change jarring, though I imagine I’ll grow accustomed to it. I’d love to learn if there are other aspects to this.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I have been sensitive to font choices for a bit over a decade: noticed this when students would hand in assignments set with different type faces. The sensitivity is enough that it can take me 30 to 45 seconds to adjust and start reading. (Which, when multiplied across many homework assignments is a few hours of my life per term. :) Sometimes though, there is no adjustment: a type face is so distinctive that it just constantly insists "Look at me!" instead of allowing me to see word forms, numerals, etc. The deplorable font in this case is 'Ubuntu' on one of my primary machines.

Comment: They've now moved from _Ubuntu_ to the still ugly, but IMO more readable, _Liberation_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a reasonable work-around on FireFox:

1. Install [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search).
2. Click Stylus' badge in the tool bar, and select Manage.
3. Select Write new style, and paste the below into it (edit as needed, e.g., add `domain("askubuntu.com"),`):

```
/* ==userstyle==
@name Stack Exchange
@namespace Steven Penny
@version 1.0.0
==/userstyle== */
@-moz-document
domain("stackexchange.com"),
domain("stackoverflow.com"),
domain("superuser.com") {
   body {
      --ff-sans: Arial;
   }
   .topbar-dialog .modal-content .message-text h4,
   .topbar-dialog,
   header {
      font-family: var(--ff-sans) !important;
   }
   .full-diff .content,
   .wmd-input,
   code {
      font-family: Consolas !important;
   }
}
```

4. Click Save.
5. Close the Stylus>Manage window, and breathe a sigh of relief.

Comment: Thank you. Can't we set up bounties for Meta questions?

Comment: Thank you Alexis! The Ubuntu font is so repellent that I was planning to use the site solely from my 'phone while I saved up for a Windows licence.

Answer (score 9):

I'm sorry that this change has harmed your experience using the site. Unfortunately, this is a system-wide change. It is out of our hands as CV moderators. More information: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1)